# dynamic jsx tag name gives error: JSX element type '...' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: typescript, jsx

code:

```
const TagName = 'div';
const element = <TagName>....</TagName> // line 2
```

This gives error on line 2:
`JSX element type 'TagName' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

I have read other similar questions with this error, but none provide a solution on how to fix for this case.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you use JSX, the tag name is not a variable value but a component.

for example:

file B:

```
export class ComponentB extends ReactComponent{

}
```

file A:

```
import {ComponentB} from 'b';

<ComponentB></ComponentB>
```

However if for some reason you want to use a variable to have a dynamic tagName (which is a wrong way to do that anyway), so you need to use braces, which make their content parse as JavaScript:

```
const TagName = 'div';
const element = <{TagName}>....</{TagName}> // line 2
```

This is a a wrong way since it's not a common practice and therefore it won't be clear to other programmers who read your code.

The common practice is like that:

```
const someCondition = 1 + 1 === 2;

{someCondition && 
<ComponentA></ComponentA>}
{!someCondition && 
<ComponentB></ComponentB>}
```

Each component will be rendered just if the left side of the expression is true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. why is it a wrong way? what is the right way to approach this issue when I want a dynamic tag name to render with jsx